# Batch create files containing the name of the folder in which they are located and other data

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a network drive (mapped locally) where the backups of each user of my organisation are stored (more than 2000).
The tree is in this form :

- **username0001**\archive
- ...
- **username0456**\archive
- ...
- **username0789**\archive
- ...
- **username2000**\archive

I would like from a batch script, create a file called "backup.conf" in each backup folder of my users, which would contain 2 lines :

[**username**]  >> *1st line*

ArchivePath=archive >> *2nd line*

With the real **username** between **[  ]**.

Do you have any idea of code that could lead to this ?

I tried the following batch script :

```
cd mynetworkmappeddriveletter: (e.g. X:)
for /d %%a in (*) do (echo %%a > %%a\backup.conf)
```

How to add the second line and **[ ]** between the username ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Show some code you tried. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. apart from that the grep command might be a good start for your search

Comment: Your title contains `bash`, but you tagged the question as windows `batch-file`. You should know what you are using

Comment: I've edited my title.

Comment: Will the network drive be mapped to a drive letter locally? For the example you provided of **username0456\archive**, should the file contain On first line `[username0456]`   and on second line `ArchivePath=archive` ?  Please edit your question to show clearer example.

Comment: Yes the network drive is mapped to a driver letter locally.

Comment: Yes on first line [username0456] and on second line ArchivePath=archive.

Answer (score 0):

No enough rep to comment.
Here's some ideas for your code from a junior :)

1. list directory name (dir)

```
admin
tech
user1
user2
user3
voucher
```

2. add a filter to only get users' folder name

```
user1
user2
user3
```

3. store the output in a text file: `f.txt` data is

```
user1
user2
user3
```

4. I guess you already know where users' folder are, so path should be known. So store it in a variable
   `"c:\mypath\"`
5. for each line in the text file, (create a file that contains what you want at the specific location

```
For user1, 
  echo "[user1]" > backup.conf
  echo "ArchivePath=c:\mypath\user1\archive" > backup.conf
For user2,
  ...
For user3,
  ...
```

It might contains batch syntax error as I'm not an expert but that the basic approach I would start with.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following batch script :

```
cd mynetworkmappeddriveletter: (e.g. X:)
for /d %%a in (*) do (echo %%a > %%a\backup.conf)
```

How to add the second line **ArchivePath=archive** and add **[ ]** between the username ?