# How do I create a multiline text file with batch?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, text, echo

I'd like from a batch script to create a text file inside each folder in a given directory with 2 lines : the first line containing the name of the folder in which the text file is located, between brackets [ ], the second line with a text of my choice.

For example :

```
[test]
abcd123
```

I started writing the code :

```
cd C:\test
for /d %%a in (*) do (echo %%a > %%a\test.txt)
```

But I have no idea how to add the brackets and a 2nd line.

Can you help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch create files containing the name of the folder in which they are located and other data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506940/batch-create-files-containing-the-name-of-the-folder-in-which-they-are-located-a)

Answer (score 1):

One of the purposes of the parentheses is to create a command block that the `FOR` command can use to execute multiple lines of code.

So use that to your advantage.

```
cd C:\test
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    echo [test]>"%%a\test.txt"
    echo %%a >>"%%a\test.txt"
)
```

Comment: It works many thanks.
This command outputs some status (e.g. "the specified path was not found" ...). How can I prevent the command from displaying anything ?